# Limit paste range to 3 columns in script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I had created a script to copy information to a second tab when a column's value is "Yes" (column 11 in the spreadsheet). However, I only want it to copy the row data for the first 3 columns (vs ALL the data from the row).

The solution I had worked fine in my initial test but when I went to use it in another spreadsheet it is now copying 10 columns worth of data when column 11 = "Yes" vs just the first 3 - Any ideas why this might be? Thank you in advance!!

```
    var destinationSheet = "Destination Sheet"
    var check = {
      "col":11,
      "changeVal": "Yes",
      "del": false ,
      };
    var pasteRange = {
      "start": 1, 
      "cols": 3
      };
    function onEdit(e) {
      var sheets = ['Source Sheet'];
      var sheet =  e.range.getSheet();
      var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
      if(sheets.indexOf(sheetName) != -1){
        var cell = e.range;
        var cellCol = cell.getColumn();
        var cellRow = cell.getRow(); 
        if(cellCol === check.col){
          if(cell.getValue() === check.changeVal){
            var exportRange = sheet.getRange(cellRow,pasteRange.start,1,pasteRange.cols);
            var pasteDestination = e.source.getSheetByName(destinationSheet);
            var pasteEmptyBottomRow = pasteDestination.getLastRow() + 1;
            exportRange.copyTo(pasteDestination.getRange(pasteEmptyBottomRow,1),
                       SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES);
            if(check.del){
              var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
              sheet.deleteRow(cellRow);
    };
   };
  };
 };
};
```

Comment: Please share a sample of your sheet.

Comment: Sounds like there may be a conflict in "pasteRange" - maybe you have that same parameter in several scripts of the same file?

Comment: Came back to look at this with some extra caffeine this morning and realized that the test row I was selecting "Yes" in contained an IMPORTRANGE function which is why that was happening! Thanks all. :)

Answer (score 1):

Script works fine! I realized that the test row I was adding "yes" for in the new sheet had an IMPORTRANGE function. Not a big deal for my purposes but if someone else wanted to use this and that was an issue, I think you might be able to get around it by using a different "CopyPasteType"! https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/copy-paste-type